# Why am I getting a value error in my google sheets query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I took an Udemy class in Google Sheets and I'm trying a formula on a similar dataset as I learned on, but I'm getting a value error. Please help.

The query is:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uJAwHzcg_MYBS08jqnWGcqe7oBIlPyVWCQN48G6tFfE/edit#gid=790495475","sephora_website_dataset2!$A:$G"),"SELECT Col2,Average(Col7) WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col2 ORDER BY Average(Col7) desc LIMIT 10",-1)
```

Here is what the dataset looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm6qx.png

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't know `Average`, use `avg` instead.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uJAwHzcg_MYBS08jqnWGcqe7oBIlPyVWCQN48G6tFfE/edit#gid=790495475","sephora_website_dataset2!$A:$G"),"SELECT Col2,avg(Col7) WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col2 ORDER BY avg(Col7) desc LIMIT 10",-1)
```

Comment: That is great thank you. I'm glad it was only a minor snafu

Answer (score 0):

The name of the average-function in your query is `avg`, not "Average".

So the correct formula would be:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uJAwHzcg_MYBS08jqnWGcqe7oBIlPyVWCQN48G6tFfE/edit#gid=790495475","sephora_website_dataset2!$A:$G"),"SELECT Col2, avg(Col7) WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col2 ORDER BY avg(Col7) desc LIMIT 10", -1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the clarification

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1uJAwHzcg_MYBS08jqnWGcqe7oBIlPyVWCQN48G6tFfE", "sephora_website_dataset2!A:G"),
 "select Col2,avg(Col7) 
  where Col2 is not null
  group by Col2 
  order by avg(Col7) desc 
  limit 10
  label avg(Col7)''", 0)
```